# notepad++ How to remove multi symbol comma,dot,Exclamation mark

Tags: replace, notepad++, symbols, removeall

Example

- Email me, new! responses ...to ?my posts
- Email me new responses to my posts

I search multi time on google . I can replace it one by one but i want a formular remove all symbol one time.
I'm try search and replace with (.|,|?|!|...|) but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape specials characters and select the option "regular expression" in the replace window. This is your regex.

```
\.|\?|!|\,
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply with image :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all pnctuation marks, use unicode property `\p{Punct}`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\p{Punct}+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Yeah . But i don't want remove " ' " . So above answer is better . Thank you .